# PHP codeigniter file upload $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

i have a simple and trouble understanding about these things in CodeIgniter.

`$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']` does not work correctly.

I receive a notice Message: `Undefined index: pic`

Here is my code

**controller:**

```
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'])){
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'],
                        'images/slideshow'.$_FILES['pic']['name']);
        }
```

**view:**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <div class="div_input">
      <label class="label_input"> picture:  </label>    
      <input type="file" id="pic" name="pic" class="file_1 " />      
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="div_input">
      <label class="label_input"> </label>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" class="form-submit" />    
      <input type="reset" value="" class="form-reset"  />  
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is output of `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'])`?

Comment: give erorr undefine index pic

Comment: try `print_r($_FILES);` & share output. Also, what is size of file?

Comment: can you check your configuration file for allowed types? `$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; ` //<-- allow all types for testing

Comment: If you want to use a framework, why aren't you using the helper classes that the framework provides?

Comment: include a check that the  _$_FILES['pic']_ array has values. i.e.  _if (isset($_FILES['pic']) && is_uploaded_file(..._

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
$_Files['pic']['tmp_name'][0];
```

Comment: what comes in echo var_dump($_FILES)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct depth-strucutre by

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

or

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

to see how the strucuture of $_FILES is.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this tutorial: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

`allowed_types` in configuration may be restricting your file upload. Change that to something like:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*'
```